# ModuleNotFoundError : no module named 'pycorenlp'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycorenlp

I need to install python wrapper for StanfordCoreNLP.

I have used `git clone https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp` and also `pip install pycorenlp` and its showing success in both the cases, but when I run `from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP`, its showing `ModuleNotFoundError`.
I checked its path if it installed or not. It is installed at "C:\Users\simra_000\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pycorenlp" using pip
and using git clone also it is installed at "C:\Users\simra_000\py-corenlp"

```
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycorenlp'

Comment: check the environment of installation and usage to be the same

Answer (score 1):

check if the module was installed by:

```
pip list
```

also you can add this code to install the module if it's not installed:

```
import pip

required_pkgs = ['pycorenlp']
installed_pkgs = [pkg.key for pkg in pip.get_installed_distributions()]

for package in required_pkgs:
    if package not in installed_pkgs:
        with suppress_stdout():
            pip.main(['install', package])
```

also check the version of python that you are used to run the script and the version of pip, for example if you are using python3 and you install the module via pip (python2) the module was installed for python v.2 only

otherwise check the name of your script, so if the name of your script is `pycorenlp.py` the import will not work, and you need to change the name of your script
hope that helps you

Comment: I checked it using pip list , it is installed

Comment: I checked the version of pip which was used to install the module, it is the same python 3.6. But I did not understand how to check the name of the script

Comment: your script name, the file that contains your code most be different from   pycorenlp.py